# How to run FastAPI server as multiple instances

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, fastapi

I have developed a FastAPI Web Application.

If I run the server and it is down or crashed for some reason. I need multiple instances of server  to be running.

I currently run the server with the following code.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run("__main__:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=5000,reload=True, workers=4)
```

What is the role of workers here? If it is running the server on 4 different processors. does that mean it has 4 instances of running the server ?

when I run the server with workers. I cant stop the server. I need to kill the server with PId.
Is there a better way to stop it?

if that's not like creating instances. How can we achieve it with FastAPI.

Comment: Use a process manager like guvicorn to make sure your server has the number of workers available. If your application is prone to dying, the user of an external process manager will allow it to be automagically restarted if any issues occur. Supervisord is another option. For distributed handling of these issues in a production environment (i.e. a physical server can die without affecting the application), look into k3s, k8s, docker swarm and other orchestration technologies.

Comment: @MatsLindh Thanks for the comment. https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/server-workers/   Is this what you are talking about  ?

Comment: Sure, that's a good reference for running gunicorn. Exactly how you make it a service that is handled automagically by your operating system depends on which OS and distribution you're running.

Answer (score 1):

notice: you can not run workers in reload=True

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
        uvicorn.run("main:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=5000, workers=4)
```

there is two way to stop it 1.terminate 2.kill pid(kill $(pgrep -P $uvicorn_pid))

Comment: Thanks for Notifying. But the solution is deviating the actual question. I'm currently using uvicorn to start server. How can I have multiple instances of it. Does adding workers=4 help to achieve it ?

Comment: I have added workers=4. but I'm not sure what's happening behind it.

Comment: its depends on your CPU cores,Uvicorn worker processes to parallelize the execution of the application, take advantage of multiple cores in the CPU, and be able to serve more requests. i suggest read https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/server-workers/ would be helpful